# TypeError when making Columns for React-Table using array of objects as Data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7

I am trying to use React-Tables to make a table of object properties...

Running React 17.0.2, React-Table 7.7.0

I get the following error which I have identified to be a type error but have no idea how to go about fixing

```
TS2345: Argument of type 
'{ tableCols: { Header: string; accessor: string; }[]; tdata: Dataset[]; }' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'TableOptions<{}>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, 
and 'tableCols' does not exist in type 'TableOptions<{}>'
```

.

The object looks somewhat like this

```
interface Dataset {
  name: string;
  time_added: string;
  image_width: number;
  image_height: number;
  minimum_frame: number;
  maximum_frame: number;
}
```

Starting the function component

```
interface DatasetListProps {}

const DatasetList = (_props: DatasetListProps) => {
```

I created a dummy data for now and am using that to fill the array

```
  const dummy: Dataset = {
    name: '',
    time_added: '',
    image_width: 0,
    image_height: 0,
    minimum_frame: 0,
    maximum_frame: 0,
  }
```

I am just trying to get the first 2 columns to show up for now.

```
  const tableCols = useMemo(() => [{
      Header: 'Name',
      accessor: 'name',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Time',
      accessor: 'time_added',
    },
  ], []);
```

Dummy data list creation

```
  const tdata = useMemo(() => [dummy, dummy], []);
```

Creating the actual dang table

```
  const tableInstance = useTable({ tableCols, tdata })
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = tableinstance
```

Then the big return statement with the table html (taken directly from docs

```
return ( 
  <table {...getTableProps()}>
    <thead>
      {// Loop over the header rows
      headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
        // Apply the header row props
        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
          {// Loop over the headers in each row
          headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
            // Apply the header cell props
            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
              {// Render the header
              column.render('Header')}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </thead>
    {/* Apply the table body props */}
    <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
      {// Loop over the table rows
      rows.map(row => {
        // Prepare the row for display
        prepareRow(row)
        return (
          // Apply the row props
          <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
            {// Loop over the rows cells
            row.cells.map(cell => {
              // Apply the cell props
              return (
                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                  {// Render the cell contents
                  cell.render('Cell')}
                </td>
              )
            })}
          </tr>
        )
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  )

}
```

End of function component

Comment: Hey @Rr9! Did you solve it? I am also wondering how to pass more data than the number of columns I have. For example I have logo and the name in data, and I want to show them both in the Name column (I don't need extra column for logo), but react-table complains with a same error as you got in your case

Comment: I couldn't fix it. For now i moved on by just mapping things to a HTML table and creating a jank substring search to look though the first row. I may revisit after backlog is a little better.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution renaming file from `.tsx` to `.jsx` worked for me. I found this in react-table open issues, looks like it won't work properly without hacks until they rewrite the library into typescript in further releases.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized your table instance incorrectly.
It should be like

```
const tableInstance = useTable({ columns: tableCols, data: tdata })
```